# How to pass variable in powershell script recipe

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have recipe which is of powershell commands

```
powershell_script "run-isci" do
code <<-EOH
Set-Service -Name msiscsi -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service msiscsi
New-IscsiTargetPortal -TargetPortalAddress 165.xx.xx.xx
Connect-IscsiTarget -NodeAddress iqn.2015.xxxx.xx -TargetPortalAddress 165.xx.xx.xx -IsPersistent $True

EOH
end
```

I am getting values `165.xx.xx.xx` and `iqn.2015.xxxx.xx` from another recipe and I wanted to pass it to this recipe.
How I can achieve this?

Comment: Store the values in separate text files and and pass them in your PowerShell script block like, 
`Connect-IscsiTarget -NodeAddress (Get-Content iqn.txt)  -TargetPortalAddress (Get-Content IP.txt) -IsPersistent $True`
This is one way of doing it.

Comment: Can we store these values in variable inside script like store in array,etc.? Actually these values are not static.

Comment: values for iqn and ip are generating on the fly from another script so i have use these file into this recipe

Comment: Yes that can be done too. Just store the value in a variable say `$variable`, at the time of its generation and pass the `$variable` in your script block, instead of the content of txt file, I mentioned earlier.

Comment: My script is like this :

require_relative 'list_att_vol'
bkp_id = List_volume_attached_XXX.list_volume_XXX('ocid1.instance.ocssadf')
ids = bkp_id.map(&:ipv4)
iq = bkp_id.map(&:iqn)

powershell_script "run-isci" do
code <<-EOH
Set-Service -Name msiscsi -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service msiscsi
New-IscsiTargetPortal -TargetPortalAddress $ids
Connect-IscsiTarget -NodeAddress $iq -TargetPortalAddress $ids -IsPersistent $True

EOH
end
First part of script will find all list of volumes ip's and iqn 
second part of script with run powershell script using run list

Comment: Could you please format your code properly. Its hard to grasp from the current looks of it.

Comment: I am sorry i am new to stackoverflow, can you please let me know how i can format code in stackoverflow, it's in formatted order in my display

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-do-i-use-formatting-in-comments).

Comment: require_relative 'list_att_vol'
bkp_id = List_volume_attached_PTC.list_volume_PTC('ocid1.instance.ocssadf') 
ids = bkp_id.map(&:ipv4)
iq = bkp_id.map(&:iqn)

powershell_script "run-isci" do 
code <<-EOH 
Set-Service -Name msiscsi -StartupType Automatic 
Start-Service msiscsi 
New-IscsiTargetPortal -TargetPortalAddress $ids 
Connect-IscsiTarget -NodeAddress $iq -TargetPortalAddress $ids -IsPersistent $True 

EOH 
end

Comment: Yes you are right i am getting multiple values for $iq and $ids and i am getting these values from ist_volume_attached_PTC.list_volume_PTC('ocid1.instance.ocs‌​‌​sadf') $ids = bkp_id.map(&:ipv4) $iq = bkp_id.map(&:iqn)

Comment: Do you intend to say your `$iq` and `$ids` contain more than one value respectively. And if I have got this right, are you obtaining the values for `$iq` and `$idsfrom` below these lines, 

`bkp_id = List_volume_attached_PTC.list_volume_PTC('ocid1.instance.ocs‌​‌​sadf') `

`$ids = bkp_id.map(&:ipv4)`

`$iq = bkp_id.map(&:iqn)`

Comment: In that case you need process the multiple values using a `foreach` loop. Or If you want to pass only the specific value, you will have to use a wild card to filter out your desired value and then pass it to your script block.

Comment: Can you please give me code ?
I am also trying from my end

Answer (score 0):

The general way you would handle this is `#{}` variable interpolation in the code string. But make sure you are very careful about Chef's two-pass model (ref: https://coderanger.net/two-pass/), passing data between recipes can be very tricky.